# azure set environment variable programmatically to disable an azure function

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-functions

I have an azure API and an Azure function. When certain logic is passed into the API, I want it to disable the Azure function.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368786/programmatically-set-azure-app-service-application-settings-environment-variab) suggest disabling the function using environment variables. This works, but in my case, I cant disable this via manual intervention, I need the api to set this variable.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your options are somewhat limited and will entail modifying some files that will enable or disable your functions.

Fortunately, you can easily to this programmatically using the [Kudu VFS API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs).

There are two files you can work with to disable or enable a function, offering you different approaches to support different patterns:

#### host.json

The `host.json` file, located on the root of your function script files, exposes a `functions` property, which is a string array that, when set, defines a functions **white list**. When this property is set, only the functions contained in this array will be enabled and loaded by the runtime.
You can find more information about that setting [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json).

#### function.json

Each function has a `function.json` file that contains function metadata. This metadata supports a `disabled` property that, when set to true, disables that function. 
This gives you the ability to manage each function individually, which defaulting to loading all functions in the app, but you do end up having to manage more files.

You can find more information about this setting [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/function.json).